# Flutter Firebase authentication : stream query return null when data are existing

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

During Firebase authentication, I query my Firebase database of users using the `firebase_id` to know if an user exist.

I have noticed that some existing users might randomly get duplicated apparently due to the fact that query with `firebase_id` parameter didnt return a result and so created another user with same `firebase_id`.

How to guarantee that Firebase stream query result is always reliable?

--- Updated below with asynMap following @Frank answer but still bug persisting ----

```
  Stream<Customer> getCustomerStream(
  {String? firebaseId, String? email, String? phoneNumber}) {
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> collectionStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('customers')
        .where('firebase_id', isEqualTo: firebaseId)
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'active')
        .orderBy('updated_at', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();

return collectionStream.asyncMap((querySnapshot) async {
  if (querySnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
 Customer customer = Customer(
      firebaseId: firebaseId,
      status: 'active',
      email: email,
      mobile: phoneNumber,
      authenticationEmail: email,
      averageRating: 5,
      updatedAt: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
      createdAt: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
    );
    customer.reference = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('customers')
        .add(customer.toMap());
    return customer;
  } else {
    Customer customer = Customer.fromSnapshot(querySnapshot.docs[0]);

    return Customer.fromSnapshot(querySnapshot.docs[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does `addNewCustomer` modify `customer` asynchronously? If so, your `return customer;` here returns the non-modified customer object.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, sorry some code was missing that I have added, you are right...
First in AddNewCustomer, "customer.id" might be null and 2nd return customer is missing the Firestore docReference, so I am adding       "customer.reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').doc(); " ...but still for this async part should i look at something with "yield" "async*"?

Comment: ok solution might be in using "collectionStream.asyncMap" and "await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').add(customer.toMap())"...I just wonders if returning my local customer after await is ok or do i forget sth and better to query again Firestore for this newly added customer